# HTTP_ACCEPT and CONTENT_TYPE mismatch after upgrade to restframework 3.7.0

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django 1.11 project running with restframework 3.6.4. 
I also use djangorestframework-jsonapi version 2.4.0.

If I check request.META in dispatch function of APIView in rest_framework/views, I have the following:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: 'application/vnd.api+json',
CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/vnd.api+json',
```

After upgrading restframework to 3.7.0, I see that in the same place:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: 'application/vnd.api+json',
CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json; charset=None'
```

I have my View which uses APIView (rest_framework.views) as a parent class.
Every POST that goes through this view gets to dispatch method of APIView.
The request that's being sent to dispatch method already has the mismatch between HTTP_ACCEPT and CONTENT_TYPE.

As a result, the wrong JSONParser is used and due to mismatches in request.data all my tests fail.

My settings are:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.metadata.JSONAPIMetadata',

    ...
}
```

The relevat commit in django-rest-framework that changes the functionality is:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/commit/0ec915e6234bdc602e131f08e8cff46fcf3dc3ff

Maybe someone has an idea why it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please add your unit tests to the question

Comment: The error happens on every POST I do in my API

Comment: @alexarsh does this affect all POST requests to your API, or does it affect the POST requests in your tests? The referenced commit only affects the `RequestFactory`, which should not affect general usage.

Comment: I have the problem both in API and in regular POSTS to my API

Comment: @alexarsh The referenced commit is not the source of the issue. If you look at what's happening, it fixes a bug where non-form type requests (e.g., `application/json`) with an *empty body* may incorrectly have their `request.data` set to a `QueryDict` instead of a `dict`. The code doesn't change anything about how the `Content-Type` header is handled.

Also, are you 100% positive that you have a *request* Content-Type of `'application/json; charset=None'`? This is usually seen in the response header, not requests. If it is the request, then this issue is originating out of the framework.

Comment: Yes, I’m sure. I see it on request

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/facb433c89ae52a618857b50a1bdf109392c380c/rest_framework/request.py#L189-L191) is the code that determines content type. As far as I can tell, there is either some request middleware or some view code that mutates the request's HTTP headers, or the client is sending the wrong content type. Can you include the code for your `dispatch` method that checks the request? The existing description isn't enough to debug this.

Comment: @alexarsh - did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Not yet. Added some more description about the flow. Before the commit that I mentioned, dispatch method gets the request where HTTP_ACCEPT and CONTENT_TYPE match and after the commit, they don't.